# Issue with JsonForm in mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use the JSONForm libary from Github to generate a html markup from a json schema. I am trying to do this in an MVC view that does not have a default form tag. I added one with html.beginform but still the markup is not generated and i get the following javascript error in console :TypeError: _ is null . Could someone help me out ?

Below is the code in the view :

```
  @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
   }

   @using (Html.BeginForm())
   { 

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/json-form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/underscore.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('form').jsonForm({
        schema: {
            name: {
                type: 'string',
                title: 'Name',
                required: true
            },
            age: {
                type: 'number',
                title: 'Age'
            }
        },
        onSubmit: function (errors, values) {
            if (errors) {

            }
            else {

            }
        }
    })



    $(document).ready(function () {

        alert('udayan');

    });





</script>







    <h2>Index</h2>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*json-form.js* depends upon underscore (`_`). You therefore need to move:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/underscore.js"></script>
```

... so that it is above:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/json-form.js"></script>
```